# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a generic Table component that will receive an array of objects and render a table component.

The parent component that consumes the `Cell` component needs to pass the `columns` (example provided below) object in order to decide what fields to be rendered from the data.

My problem is, in my `Cell` component, I am trying to render the content of that row for the specified column, it gives me `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.` error.

Here are my type definitions and Cell component.

Note: The `Cell` component receives a generic type for the shape of the data.

ColumnType

```
interface ColumnType<D> {
  field: Exclude<keyof typeof D, symbol>; // Excluding symbol as it gives some other errors
}
```

Cell component props

```
interface ICellProps<D> {
  row: D;
  col: ColumnType<D>;
}
```

Cell component

```
function Cell<D>(props: ICellProps<D>) {
  const { row, col } = props;

  return <td>{row[col.field]}</td>; // Error happens here for row[col.field]
}
```

Basically, for this example data;

```
const data = [
  { name: "John", age: 25 },
  { name: "Jane", age: 21 },
];
```

and for this list of columns;

```
const columns = [
  { field: "name", verbose: "Name" },
  { field: "age", verbose: "Age" },
];
```

I want the `row` object to only accept "name" and "age", which should be the case here because, inside the `Cell` component, `col` type seems like `ColumnType<D>` but it gives me the following error:

[image: TypeScript error]

If I write it as `row[col.field as keyof D]` the error disappears but I am looking for a solution that solves the problem inside my type definitions. I am not 100% sure what's the best approach here. I thought, the way I designed my type definitions, It should have worked because `row` is `type of D` and `col.field` is `keyof D`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In ColumnType, is `keyof *typeof* D` is intended? When I paste that into a TS environment, I get a compiler error. If I remove the `typeof` then both ColumnType as well as your Cell component successfully type.

Comment: @y2bd good catch!  That is for sure the issue.

Comment: When I do that, I receive another error in my parent `Table` component where I pass the columns object: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof MyData'.ts(2322)` Your solution turns `field` into a string type, but I want `field` to be only and only the keys of `D`

Comment: @SametM. that would probably warrant a separate question

Comment: @SametM. You want `keyof D`.  You don't want `keyof typeof D` because `D` is already a type.  Is that what you are doing?